# Looking for ECMAScript parser for ,net

Tags: javascript, parsing

I would like to build a tool to auto-document JavaScript script files.
I am looking for a .Net component that will parse ECMAScript 5.0 scripts such that I can enumerate every method, determine parameter types and properties etc.

Is there such a library out there that can provide this type of functionality.

Comment: All of those are impossible in general without running the javascript, especially determining parameter types (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AjaxMin](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) does that.

However, Javascript does not have parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS).  It is a complete JavaScript runtime implemented in .Net.  However, it is only stable with ECMAScript 3.

There is an [ECMAScript 5 branch](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS/tree/ecmascript5) in their repository, but I am uncertain of its status.

There are some other interpreters referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382966/javascript-interpreter-for-net).  Perhaps some of them are ES5 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try [EcmaScript.NET](https://code.google.com/p/ecmascript-net/), is it something you are looking for?