# With WebBrowser control, invoking a javascript function doesn't fire DocumentCompleted event

Tags: javascript, browser, compact-framework

In my C# code, I'm using a WebBrowser control in a Form to display my data.
Initially I fill in my data through a 
     webViewer.DocumentText = someHtml;  (1)
This one produces the sequence of Navigating, Navigated, and DocumentCompleted events, as expected.

Then at a later stage I make some calls to
    webViewer.Navigate(new Uri("javascript:myFunction(x,y)")); (2)
Since I'm on the Compact Framework, I understand this is the only way to call some javascript. (as seen in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135586/call-javascript-function-from-net-compact-framework-in-webbrowser-control)) 
Now, in terms of events, I only receive the Navigating event, and that's it..., not the other ones. WebBrowser.ReadyState will also stay at "Loading" forever. I'm a bit puzzled by this behaviour.

I've dumbed down myFunction to the simplest one to prove that this behaviour wasn't related to the actual content of that function (as if it was containing an endless loop or some critical errors).

While myFunction is indeed called, the ReadyState stuck in Loading state will prevent further updates of the DocumentText as done in (1), which prevents further normal execution.

I imagine I might have missed something about the use of this control, maybe there's a way to reset its state if it doesn't happen automatically, but I'm running out of ideas. Any hint?